# Make lightning-input Label as P1 font and value as P2

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

```
<lightning-input
            data-validate
            data-automation="lastname"
            label={_lastNameLabel}
            readonly={_readOnly}
            value={lastName}
            required={lastNameRequired}
            oncommit={handleLastNameChange}
            message-when-value-missing={_emptyFieldLabel}
            placeholder=""
        ></lightning-input>
```

How to change the label to P1 font and its value to P2 font?

Answer (score 0):

You can not apply different fonts directly to the label and value of `lightning-input`. You can use below code to workaround for this:

```
<div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
     <span style="font: 16px Verdana;"> Input Box: </span>
     <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter some text" variant="label-hidden" style="font: 14px Arial;"></lightning-input>
</div>
```

Output::
[image]